# Django: Extremely Large Queryset Slow to Execute (non-linear retrieval time)

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models, django-views

I am having Django (Oracle backend, cx_Oracle 5.2.1) execute a query that is a very simple

```
   select x.y, x.z from x where x.a = 'foo' and x.b = 'bar'
```

Both x.a and x.b are indexed (db_index=True)

The page I use calculates summary statistics on various records using Pandas, so the data sizes are quite large.

I have one page loading a subset of ~15000 records. This takes ~2 seconds to load

The exact same page, when using a different timeframe, but using the same type of query loads ~50000 records. It takes ~30 seconds to load. I've benchmarked performance, and Pandas is not the bottleneck.

The simple

```
my_queryset.all().values(('y', 'z'))
```

takes the overwhelming majority of the time (~90%)

Is there any reason why this is, or any way to speed it up?

Of note, when executing these queries in a database console, they are both very fast. It seems to be the Django ORM that has issues.

Comment: I am thinking you want `my_queryset.values_list('x', 'y', flat=True)`.

Comment: Or perhaps try `my_queryset.objects.only('x', 'y')`.

Comment: And judging from your top query, you want to use `filter` so you aren't returning the entire dataset.